# JQuery and animate backgroundPosition no longer works in version 1.5.0 from Google CDN

Tags: jquery

I recently upgraded from loading JQuery 1.4.4 to 1.5.0 with Google CDN.  When I upgraded, my backgroundPosition animations stopped functioning.

For example, I used to have:

`$(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: ['-1800px 0px', 'easeOutExpo']},5000);`

This no longer works in version 1.5.0 loaded from Google CDN.  Let it be noted that I am using JQuery UI 1.8.9, also loaded from Google CDN.

Has anyone else encountered similar problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a known bug, it's breaking quite a few things with jQuery UI.  My recommendation, for the interim is just refer to an older jQuery version, something like this:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: Well, it's good to know I'm not going crazy, but damn, I spent a bunch of time tracking this one down.

Answer (score 0):

1.4.4 is the last version that works with background-position, i know i spent days trying to debug my code, without knowing that fact.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it working up to 1.8.3. It looks like Keith Wood the creator updated it June 2013. You should really check out his page. [Here](http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html)