# Why can't I animate backgroundPosition past jquery 1.4.4?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate, background-position

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075368/jquery-and-animate-backgroundposition-no-longer-works-in-version-1-5-0-from-goog) that the lack of `backgroundPosition` animation in jquery 1.5.0 is a known bug.  Has it still not been fixed?

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/Tfnhf/), with `backgroundPosition` animating in jquery 1.4.4, and then look at this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/Tfnhf/1/), and see that it isn't working even in jquery 1.7.1.

Any idea when they're going to fix this?

I'm wondering because I just saw a warning in my Chrome console saying this:

> event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. 
>   They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

I'm worried that I'm going to continue to use jquery 1.4.4 for the animating functionality, but then Chrome will pull the functionality in the next update.

### UPDATE

The accepted answer, the idea to use background-position-x and y doesn't work with Firefox.  For now I'm going to have to go back to 1.4.4, until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `background-position-x` and `-y` separately like so:

```
$('div').animate({
  'background-position-x': '-6000px', 'background-position-y': '-200px' }, 4000);
```

**[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/Tfnhf/2/)** (jQuery 1.7.1)

As a side note, since your `background-position-y` isn't changing, you can simply omit that extra line and just change your `-x`.

Comment: Sure! Glad to help. Awesome research you did, btw. Bet you're kicking yourself. :p

Comment: Turns out this is incompatible with Firefox.  I'm using 8.0.1. Suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, not compatible with FireFox, this is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here: ["puff of smoke" effect javascript sprite animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148298/puff-of-smoke-effect-javascript-sprite-animation/10149377)

It seems newer versions of jQuery above 1.4.4 enable smooth background scrolling effects at a cost of breaking sprite animations that are in fact jerky relying on persistence of vision. I'd say the animate function was not intended for this, but it just worked (TM) back then.

To make my background-position sprite animation I wrote a function using setTimeout

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7Ek4/22/

It's more low level but it isn't a lot more code at all.